# On a structure object falling out of scope

Tags: c++, struct, destructor, stdvector

Header:

```
class Class{
    //...
};

struct structTest{
    std::vector<Class> stdvectorTest;
};
```

Implementation:

```
structTest structTest_Object;
//...
```

When `structTest_Object`falls out of scope, what will happen to `structTest_Object.stdvectorTest`? I remember `struct` is similar to `class` and destructor of `std::vector` frees memory.

Comment: You just answered your own question. Everything is destroyed in reverse order of initialization, as usual. Your vector is destroyed when its containing struct is destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct` is the same as `class` but for the default access level.

The member `stdvectorTest` is properly disposed of, as well as all `Class` objects inside it.

Comment: `struct` defaulting to public access, and `class` defaulting to private.

Answer (score 2):

Because structTest owns stdvectorTest as a value type, its destructor will be invoked.  And since the vector contains your classes by value as well, their destructors will also be invoked.